# Magento cluster/load balance set up

Tags: magento, scalability, load-balancing, cluster-computing

I am planning to set up Magento in a cluster with load balancing, so is it possible to have two Magento installations pointing to the same database?

If it possible - how should I configure the base url for these servers? Should the servers have the same name?

Answer (score 2):

Usually the load balancer that chooses to what server you will be redirected, so, you URL will keep the same for both servers.

Are you setting up Magento over Amazon EC2/ELB?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

1. for load balancer you can use [Pound](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=pound&f=1), it is very easy to setup.
2. when installing magento as backend (in the first installation page), you must fill with same database configuration (host, database name, user name, user password).
3. for "Base URL", fill with IP of load balancer, then checked the "Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step"
4. on "Session Storage Options" you must choose "Database", so all magento backend will use same server as database and session storage
5. you shouldn't have the same name for each server